# Cant seem to convert int to a string within linq expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the following error on the following procedure

```
public Patient getPatientByPatientId(int PatientID)
{
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    if (PatientID == -1)
    {
       patient = new Patient();
    }
     else
    {
       using (var myContext = new SMBASchedulerEntities(this.Connectionstring))
        {
                patient = myContext.Patients
               .Where(w => w.PatientID == Convert.ToString(PatientID)).FirstOrDefault();
         }
        }
        return patient;
}
```

The error is

> n unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Comment: Use `PatientID.ToString()` instead

Comment: your `Patient.PatientID` is a string?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your code

```
patient = myContext.Patients.Where(w => w.PatientID == Convert.ToString(PatientID)).FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
patient = myContext.Patients.Where(w => w.PatientID ==PatientId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above query with assuming that `PatientId` is `String`

But Error says *`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(**Int32**)' method`*

Means `PatientId` is `Int`.

Then try with following code

```
patient = myContext.Patients.Where(w => w.PatientID ==PatientId).FirstOrDefault();
```